# Computing hashcode of combination of value type and array

Tags: c#, hashcode

It seems I cannot understand the documentation of Hashcode struct:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode?view=net-5.0

I tried a naive:

```
public struct S : IEquatable<S>
{
    public int I { get; set;  }
    public string[] A { get; set;  }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj) => obj is S s && Equals(s);

    public bool Equals(S other) => I == other.I && StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(A, other.A);

    // public override int GetHashCode() => I.GetHashCode() ^ StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(A);
    public override int GetHashCode() => HashCode.Combine(I, A);
}
```

Which lead to:

```
S s1 = new S() { I = 42, A = new string[] { "hello" } };
S s2 = new S() { I = 42, A = new string[] { "hello" } };
Assert.Equal(s1.GetHashCode(), s2.GetHashCode());
```

Giving an error:

> ```
> Xunit.Sdk.EqualException: 'Assert.Equal() Failure
> Expected: 840823323
> Actual:   -1160370390'
> ```

What is the right way to use `HashCode.Combine` (I did not like my earlier XOR solution) ?

Answer (score 2):

You're using `HashCode.Combine` correctly. The problem is that you're using `StructuralEqualityComparer` for the equality comparison but not for the hash code generation, so the two strings arrays are "equal" but do not generate the same hash code by default. Use

```
public override int GetHashCode() => HashCode.Combine(I, 
       StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(A));
```

This is necessary because `Combine` will call `GetHashCode` on each instance, which for lists will be different regardless of the values in the list. So you need to specify *how* you want to generate the hash code.

Comment: Upstream documentation should really make it clear that one can pass the result of a previous `GetHashCode` call...otherwise this look like black magic to me. Thanks !

Comment: The documentation assumes you know how hash codes for reference types work. By default, the hash code for a reference type is different for each instance regardless of "value". It clearly states that it combines the hash codes for the parameters, so it will get the hash code for the _list_, which will be unique regardless of value. To guarantee the same hash codes, you need to specify _how_ to compute the hash code for `A`.  That detail is true for hash codes in general and is not specific to `HashCode.Combine`

Comment: @malat The only reason it works is because `int.GetHashCode` *always just returns itself*.  So technically this code *is* getting a hashcode of a hashcode, not a hashcode of the actual object itself, but it just so happens that *those things are always the same* because of how `int.GetHashCode` is implemented.  Note you *can* use `HashCode.Add` to add the hashes, and it takes an explicit comparer, which is the "technically correct" way of doing it, but isn't actually *necessary* for it to work.

Comment: @Servy that was the part I was missing, thanks much !